# Can anyone identify this badge?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike, vintage

I’m in the process of restoring my Dad’s bike so that I can start riding again. All the badges are intact but I can’t find any information about the bike. He’s had it for as long as I can remember (my whole life) so I’m assuming it was made in Japan in the 1970’s. Can anyone identify this badge?

[image]

---

Edit: I don’t believe it’s a Hero.  The sticker on the up tube says “Made in Japan.” I’ve searched a few Japanese manufactures that I found on Wikipedia but couldn’t find a Hawk reference on the few hyperlinks I could access.

Here is an image of the bike.[image]

Please keep in mind that the handle bars, seat and front fork in this image are not the originals. It’s a standard 10 speed road bike.

Comment: You should also add an image of the entire bike if possible and any other distinguishing decals or parts.

Comment: There are a couple of head tube badges with "hawk" on them in a google image search, but they're to expired ebay auctions and pintrest, and lack further information.  A photo of the whole bike might help.

Comment: There is a Hawk brand made by Hero in India since the 1950s.  Could it be one of them?   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_Cycles

Comment: Is there anything distinctive about the seat tube decal? Can you post a closeup of that?

Comment: Probably no later than 1975 .  Likely the handlebars and brake levers have been changed.

Comment: A couple things on this bike. First it having made in Japan, just dates it to the 70s. after the 70s bike brands moved to Taiwan to get their bikes made cheaper. Almost all major brands were made in Japan in the 70s. The 70s was also a giant bike boom, with many companies coming and going very fast as major brands took over the market. I have never seen anything of this sort of head badge before, and can't seem to find anything that would even slightly point me in the right direction to find the brand.

Answer (score 2):

The Australian police have some Hawk bikes, and there is an Australian company "Hawk Racing" I mention this as there appears to be two Boomerangs on the badge. Should that read "Hawk CCM"  "Hawk ? Cycle Manufacture"
Of course this could be a resellers badge and manufactured elsewhere.

ref [police](http://bicycles.net.au/forums/viewtopic.php?t=6930)

ref [company](https://www.facebook.com/HawkRacingAUS/?hc_ref=ART_WDznEyEGMoW9CzuWvo3I0witJ28CbSDCMYE6YK2FVCsRIIHN10GR5CQe-OrNTG4&fref=nf)

Answer (score 0):

I found a 10 speed Azuki (edited: black hawk is not the model :) ) that looks close if not the same (can't see the badge). It's from an ad that claims to be from the 80s (see link).

http://www.shoppok.com/rapidcity/a,28,76203,Azuki-10-speed-bicycle--made-in-Japan----50--Black-Hawk-.htm

[image: bike]

Comment: The cottered crank makes it doubtful that it's newer than maybe 1978.  And the lugs in the above picture are different from those in the OP's.